# Sending email without keyfile (only certfile) using Python smtplib

Tags: python, email, smtp, python-2.6

Trying to send email with a certificate file using the following script:

```
import smtplib

client = smtplib.SMTP(myhost, myport)
client.ehlo()
client.starttls(certfile=mycertfile)
client.ehlo()

client.login(myusername, mypassword)
client.sendmail(sender, receiver, Message)
client.quit()
```

I get the following error:

```
SSLError: error:140B0009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:PEM lib
```

I think documentations ([smtplib.html](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.starttls) and [ssl.html](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html)) say I need to provide a private key. I only have the certificate file (base64 PEM format). My devops says that a private key is not required in this case because I do not need to identify the local side of the connection.

### Question

Is there a way to send the email without providing the private key? If a private key is required, why?

Comment: The error refers to SSLv3 either because one of the implementations (client or server) downgraded the connection from TLSv1 to SSLv3, or because OpenSSL reuses error codes for the two implementations (there are few changes from SSLv3 to TLSv1). There's not much else to say about the error, it means your certificate file doesn't include the server's cert nor a trust chain to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to use SSL/TLS: client authenticated and "basic" where the client is unauthenticated. In client authenticated connections, the both the server and the client send a certificate to the other. In "basic" only the server does.

If you pass neither a certificate nor a keyfile, `smtplib` will use a basic connection, where the client is authenticated.

If you use a certificate, it will be used for a client authenticated connection. In that case, the server will demand that the client shows it owns the certificate by signing a handshake message. For the client to be able to do that it also needs the private key, which can be either in the certificate file or as a separate keyfile.

Long story short, if you want to use a client certificate, you must also use a key. If not, you can just leave both empty.

---

OTOH, maybe you have a server certificate file or CA list you want to use with the connection?

In that case you need to pass it to `ssl.wrap_socket` in the `ca_certs` parameter. Since you use Python 2.6 there's no easy way to do that with `smtplib` (Python 3.3+ has a `context` argument to [starttls](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.starttls)).

How to solve this depends on your application. For example, if you do not need `ssl` for anything else, a hackish solution would be to monkey-patch `ssl.wrap_socket` with one that provides your `ca_cert` (as well as `cert_reqs=CERT_REQUIRED`, likely).

A more full blown solution would be to extend `smtplib.SMTP` with your own variant that does allow passing in those parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a monkey-patch taken from this [page](https://github.com/cybercase/django-smtp-starttls/blob/master/django_smtp_starttls.py):

```
class SMTPExt(smtplib.SMTP):
    """
    This class extends smtplib.SMTP and overrides the starttls method
    allowing extra parameters and forwarding them to ssl.wrap_socket.
    """

    def starttls(self, keyfile=None, certfile=None, **kwargs):
        self.ehlo_or_helo_if_needed()
        if not self.has_extn("starttls"):
            raise SMTPException("STARTTLS extension not supported by server.")
        (resp, reply) = self.docmd("STARTTLS")
        if resp == 220:
            self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(self.sock, keyfile, certfile, **kwargs)
            self.file = SSLFakeFile(self.sock)
            # RFC 3207:
            # The client MUST discard any knowledge obtained from
            # the server, such as the list of SMTP service extensions,
            # which was not obtained from the TLS negotiation itself.
            self.helo_resp = None
            self.ehlo_resp = None
            self.esmtp_features = {}
            self.does_esmtp = 0
        return (resp, reply)
```

Using the root cert from [requests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/cacert.pem)