# Sending email with python 2.7 to Gmail and avoiding Gmail red lock security warning

Tags: python, ubuntu, smtplib

I'm sending email thru Python using Cox.net SMTP servers.  However, the emails come to gmail with the red padlock with an 'x' through it icon and the warning says:

security:   cox.net did not encrypt this message

Here's the very simple code I'm using on Ubuntu.

```
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.cox.net', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login('myloginname','****')
    server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
    server.quit()
```

I'd really like to avoid having my emails receive that message.  I tried using the SSL port 465, and using a default SSL context with no avail.  I also tried extending smtplib.SMTP using the code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34501469 but was unable to figure out how I need to generate the cert/key files to pass to the function.

Comment: I think such a message has more to do with the SMTP server you're using than your code, as it's to do with how the message is transmitted from the SMTP server to the receiving server (in this case Gmail), not how the message goes from the client to the SMTP server. Have you tried sending email through Cox.net's SMTP server using an email client (like Thunderbird) or their webmail, and if so, does that get the same red padlock?