# how to use a p12 file and a crt file with python for sending emails

Tags: python

One of my customers demands I sign the emails I send to him.
He asked me to order a crt and a p12 file.

I have them.

For sending him emails, I am using the stmplib library in python 3. Ho w to use stmplib to send him signed emails that prove the emails were coming from me.

I have ordered these files, crt and p12 file, via the email in question. they are this attached to this email address.

Has someone a sample of program with sendmail/STMPlib that use p12 and crt file for signing the email ?

This is my code:

```
import smtplib
import sys
import ssl

smtp_server = smtplib.SMTP(server, port=587)
smtp_server.ehlo()
smtp_server.starttls()
smtp_server.login(login,password)
smtp_server.send_message(msg)
```

Many thanks,

K.

Comment: You can sign data using GPG, and python has a lib for it: https://pythonhosted.org/python-gnupg/#signing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending email without keyfile (only certfile) using Python smtplib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250020/sending-email-without-keyfile-only-certfile-using-python-smtplib)

Comment: hanks but that does help.My custoemr needs to received in its outlook a header saying: signe dby: myemail adress. When I install the certificates into outlook and when I send the email from outlook, it is ok but for massmailing,I can't use outlook.